# Opening a Form on new Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I would like to open an existing form on a new thread, with its own values (in the text fields, etc.)

This is the code I have:

```
Dim NewForm As New Form2
NewForm.Textbox1.text = "This is a test"
NewForm.Textbox2.text = "This is the other field"
NewForm.Show()
```

How would I go with opening `NewForm` on a separate thread?

Comment: It's possible to do, but why do you think you need this?

Comment: Please see VB version next to c#

Comment: It's possible but just don't do it. When you think you need another thread then you have misunderstood the event-driven nature of windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample code, how to do it if you already running one form

In your Main form constructor

```cs
 // Mark existing thread
 Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "First";
 this.Click += delegate(object a, EventArgs b) { MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name); };

 // Start new thread
 ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(NewThread);
 Thread t = new Thread(ts);
 t.Name = "Second";
 t.Start();
```

VB

```
' Mark existing thread
 Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "First"
 AddHandler me.Click, Sub(a As Object, b As EventArgs) MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)

 ' Start new thread
 Dim ts As New ThreadStart(NewThread)
 Dim t As New Thread(ts)
 t.Name = "Second"
 t.Start()
```

Now, method to open the form

```cs
 private void NewThresd() 
 {

     Form f = new Form();
     f.Text = "dfsdfsdfsdfsd";
     f.Click += delegate(object a, EventArgs b) { MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name); };
     f.ShowDialog(); 
 }
```

VB:

```
Private Sub NewThresd()

    Dim f As New Form()
    f.Text = "dfsdfsdfsdfsd"
    AddHandler f.Click, Sub(a As Object, b As EventArgs) MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)
    f.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

What this will do is, it will start a thread and open a form in it. When you click on the form it will show you name of the thread to prove that you do run your forms on different threads.

Keep in mind, this is not a production-ready code. Threads are marked and click events are wired for display of concept. Also, For example, this is not good because there will be memory leaks here

```
f.Click += delegate(object a, EventArgs b) { MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name); };
```

You should have on the class level

```
private EventHandler _hndlr = delegate(object a, EventArgs b) { MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name); };
```

VB

```
Private _h As EventHandler = Sub(a As Object, b As EventArgs) MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)
```

Then you wire the handler

```
f.Click += _hndlr;
```

VB

```
AddHandler f.Click, _hndlr
```

Then, when closing the form - unwire

```
f.Click -= _hndlr;
```

VB

```
RemoveHandler f.Click, _hndlr
```

Comment: @davidsbro Sorry, added VB

Comment: MessageBox.Show() is  a special static method. It is thread-safe and not a good test case for what is being asked here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Why? It works just fine, displaying correct name of the thread

Comment: I didin't say it wouldn't work. I said it doesn't demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using Application.run(), example:

```
  Dim NewForm As Form2 = New Form2()
                        NewForm.Textbox1.text = "This is a test"
                        NewForm.Textbox2.text = "This is the other field"
                        Application.Run(NewForm)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with this error: `Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.`??